# Whats forcing the menu to go to the left?

Tags: html, css

I am using the menu from

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp

but whenever I use it in my code, the menu is always on the left of the screen rather than in the page section.

I am using a div with the following css :-

```
    .page {
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Instead of the menu being in the 1000px, its just displays on the left.

Comment: Always add your code to the question, please don't link. Show how you are using it in your code, otherwise we're just making assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

You are just setting a `max-width`, which is more of an assertion than a property - the width will never exceed `1000px`. You never actually set the width, though.

```
.page {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Unless you need `max-width` for something else, it's safe to ommit it if you're not using relative sizing (percents or `vw`/`vh`).

Comment: Sadly, the menu still appears outside of the main section tho but thx for the pointer.

Comment: Sure, any time!